# Why are java hibernate-mapped objects encouraged to be POJO's?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, javabeans, pojo

Is it discouraged to have "extra" functionality inside a hibernate javabean? For example, a "save", "publish", or even static "get by id" method? And other potential variables such as locks, bells and whistles?

If so, where are we supposed to put these extra features that are supposed to be in each object we are dealing with? If for example we created a wrapper class ArticleWrapper that includes the POJO Article as its own private member variable, which doesn't have a mapping to Hibernate, then it wouldn't work because Hibernate can only get a list of Articles, not a list of ArticleWrappers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reasons for this are because they follow a specific well tested pattern for this, but that is not the only pattern to deal with database manipulation.

The one you describe sounds more like the [Active Record Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) Pattern.

Some frameworks implement Active Record and then their object models mix data and functionality together, pretty much like you describe. I have seen this pattern in [Ruby on Rails Active Records](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) and in Python's framework named [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/).

In this pattern every domain object represents a row in the database and carries both data and behavior.

Martin Fowler in his book on Enterprise Application Architecture Patterns (and corresponding [catalog page](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)) mentions a few other well known ways to deal with your data source layer:

- [Table Data Gateways](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)
- [Row Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html)
- [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)
- [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html)

The book and the catalog delves into many other patterns for object-relational mapping.

**Layered Design**

In the classical way you describe with Hibernate, the entities are just placeholders for data, but contain no logic whatsoever. Under this pattern you would most likely have a data access layer or repository layer around your entities that deals with recovering entities from the underlying data source and updating them back.

This layer is the one that deals with [CRUD operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

```
interface ArticleRepository {
   Article findById(Integer articleId);
   List<Article> findByAuthor(Integer authorId);
   Article save(Article article);
   void delete(Integer articleId);
}
```

On top of this layer, you have a service layer which is the one that exposes the *business logic* to the users of your application.

```
interface ArticleService {
   void publishArticle(String author, Date date, String title, String contents);
   List<Article> getFeaturedArticles(Date date);
   void unpublishArticle(Integer articleId);
}
```

On top of this layer, most likely you define some form of integration layer to expose this service layer to the application users in many different ways, like through RESTful or SOAP Web services, or RMI, EJBs or whatever other technology you know out there.

By not putting any kind of logic in your entities, they serve well their purpose of data carriers and can be reused in different service layers if necessary.

You may want to take a look at the framework like [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) that fosters this type of design. It makes it all more clear where every piece should go.

Answer (score 0):

I guess writing code is not only about making it compiling and running. To make code clean and easy to maintain developers have come up with various design patterns such as `DataAccessObject` (or dao) for this particular situation. Following OO good practices will make developers' work more efficient, especially if they work on big projects, with time code that doesn't present decent level of cohesion and looks like a bucket of dirty laundry will become impossible to maintain. Remember - just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I am confused by your vague answer. What are you suggesting that I do in this case?

Comment: If each hibernate-mapped object needs extra functionality custom-made for each object, such as publish(), how can I do it without putting them in the object itself? Should it be "Visitor" design pattern? Even that would require adding some extra stuff too, right?